# How to subset lists until specific condition is met (Using logical operators,loops or function)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I had a txt file which contained info regarding SAT scores by each state. I created 3 empty list and appended using following code. Now,  I would like to subset the list such that output display statenames with verbal score >20. Below is my example of the dataset:

```
  filepath=open('myfile.txt','r')
   l=[]
   states=[]
   verbals=[]
   maths=[]
  for h in filepath:
     n=h.strip()
     b=n.split()
     l.append(b)
  for (state,verbal,math) in l:
       states.append(state)
       verbals.append(verbal)
        maths.append(math)

 filepath.close()



  State      Verbal  Math
    NY          50      100
    NJ          10       90
    DC          25       50
   Carolina     40      10
```

I tried below code but got error

```
Verbal[verbal>20]

**Error:**'>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Being a newbie to python if you could provide the explanation with code that will be great!

Comment: What your lists name? Does `Verbal` contain all the scores for it?

Comment: @BernardL..yes Verbal contains all scores to it..

Comment: @jpp.. please see above for more clarification. Please let me know if more info is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
state = ['NY','NJ','DC','Carolina']
verbal = [50,10,25,40]
math = [100,90,50,10]
for idx, _ in enumerate(verbal):
  if verbal[idx] > 20:
    print("State {0}: Verbal {1}: Math {2}".format(state[idx], verbal[idx], math[idx]))
```

or using Tuples:

```
satScore = [('NY', 50, 100), ('NJ', 10, 90), ('DC', 25, 50), ('Carolina', 40, 10)]
for idx, _ in enumerate(satScore):
  if satScore[idx][1] > 20:
    print("State {0}: Verbal {1}: Math {2}".format(satScore[idx][0], satScore[idx][1], satScore[idx][2]))
```

**Output:**

State NY: Verbal 50: Math 100
State DC: Verbal 25: Math 50
State Carolina: Verbal 40: Math 10

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because list do not support selecting data in that manner.

You can use list comprehension to select only the scores according to what you want, which is pretty similar to the concept you have but is applied to each item in the list and returns only those that match.

```
Verbal_above20 = [i for i in verbals if i > 20]
```

But because of the way you store your data, it will be difficult to get the other parts of your data corresponding to a key. I highly suggest you check out [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for work regarding cleaning and munging data.